# not rounding to one digit

Tags: python

My last problem is floating the average to 1 decimal place, ex. av- 34.1

here is my current code:

```
total = 0.0
count = 0
data = float(input("Enter a number or enter to quit: "))
while data != "":
    count += 1
    number = float(data)
    total += number
    data = float(input("Enter a number or enter to quit: "))
    try:
        data = int(data)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    average = round(total) / count
    if data == 999:
        break
    elif data >= 100:
        print("error in value")
    elif data <= 0:
        print("error in value")   


print("These", count, "scores average as: ", round(average, 1))
```

Comment: The error `unorderable types: str() >= int()` does not match the title of this question, and the solutions are not the same.

Comment: Replace `pass` in the `except` with `break` to exit the loop when the user enters `''`.

Comment: it works with pass oddly, but it wont float by 1 decimal

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what you mean.  Can you explain?  Also what does "not executing with lit" mean?

Comment: After the last edit, this question is incoherent. Can you update it to show what issue you're having for people who didn't read the original version?

Comment: You should be keeping the original questions, and then adding the other questions as updates, not rewriting the question.  Actually, you really should be making new questions each time you have a new question.  As it is, I see a couple of things that still need fixing, but I'm not going to bother answering because when I do you will probably change the question and make my answer irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input()` returns a string, not an integer. To convert it to an integer, use `int()`:

```
data = int(input("Enter a number or enter to quit: "))
```

In python 3, you can not compare a string to an integer, hence the error. In python 2 you actually can.

If you want to also check if the user inputs an empty string, you can do:

```
data = input("Enter a number or enter to quit: ")
try:
    data = int(data)
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Comment: @user2825185 Put `if data == ''` before the other if statements